# Core Data : No NSValueTransformer with class name XXX was found for attribute YYYY on entity ZZZZ

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have my CoreData model set in a xcdatamodel file.

My attribute YYYY has a type transformable and I set the tranformer name in the Data model inspector.

I my case I was storing a `[CLLocation]` in my model.

```
class LocationArrayTransformer : NSValueTransformer {


    override func transformedValue(value: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {

        let locations = value as! [CLLocation]

        return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(locations)
    }

    override func reverseTransformedValue(value: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {

        let data = value as! NSData

        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data)
    }


}
```

That's my value transformer.

But somehow I'm still getting the warning in the console : `No NSValueTransformer with class name XXX was found for attribute YYYY on entity ZZZZ`

Any Idea why ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I spent way to much time on this to not share the solution I found :

I had to make the `NSValueTransformer` subclass available to Objc.

```
@objc(LocationArrayTransformer)
class LocationArrayTransformer : NSValueTransformer {
 ....
}
```

Simple as that.

---

As @Sbooth points out, Swift classes are namespaced. Using `@objc` makes the class available without namespacing. So setting the transformer name as `MyApp.Mytransformer` works well too !

Comment: Swift classes are namespaced and using the `@objc` makes the class available without any namespacing.  The class should be available in objc if you identify it by the Swift module name (usually your app's name) and the class: `MyCoreDataApp.LocationArrayTransformer`.

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thanks for the heads-up !

Comment: I better not asked how much time you've spent to find this solution, but I can tell you that you saved me a ton. thx

Comment: Exactly `@objc(LocationArrayTransformer)` does the trick. Thanks

Comment: Thanks from 2022 ) 
Answer from the first google link, rare beast these days. )

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for your time on figuring out the answer and for sharing with the rest of us to benefit from your hard work.  This had the working answer that I needed.