# Core Data : No NSValueTransformer with class name XXX was found for attribute YYY on entity ZZZ for custom `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer`

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

I already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597065/core-data-no-nsvaluetransformer-with-class-name-xxx-was-found-for-attribute-yy) post which is about the same warning but I already have that approach and it does not fix this issue now in iOS 17 and Xcode 15.

My use case is very simple, I have this custom transformer:

```
@objc(CustomSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer)
final class CustomSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer: NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer {
    
    override class var allowedTopLevelClasses: [AnyClass] {
        return [NSDateComponents.self]
    }
    
    static let name = NSValueTransformerName(rawValue: String(describing: CustomSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer.self))
    
    public static func register() {
        let transformer = CustomSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer()
        ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(transformer, forName: name)
    }
}
```

which is set to the Core data entity's "Transformer":

[image]

which leads to the following warning in Xcode 15:

> /Users/..../CoreData:1:1 no NSValueTransformer with class name
> 'CustomSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer' was found for attribute
> 'testDate' on entity 'MyTestObject'

App works just fine and there are no problems, but this warning is shown.

[Here](https://github.com/VladimirAmiorkov/CustomNSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer) is a sample project.

Comment: Did you register it before loading the store?

Comment: Yes, I am doing it inside `application(_:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` but the warning is still there. Actually this warning comes up even only on a build (not built and run).

Comment: This happens before I set up your persistent container.

Comment: You need to register/load the store before accessing any objects.

Comment: I created a simple test project that shows the setup (not much to it :) ) https://github.com/VladimirAmiorkov/CustomNSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer

Comment: I have this same issue, nothing changed, it just started warning with the latest Xcode... if you find a solution please do share 

Comment: Everybody hitting this issue should report it to Apple. Eventually they should fix it: it is clearly a bug in the CoreData model compiler.

Comment: It already has been reported here https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/740492 but there is no official response.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution.
It’s a workaround as the behavior we’re dealing with is clearly a bug in `momc`.

My solution is to remove the transformer name from the transformer name attribute of the attributes in the model, and set it in the user info of the property instead. Then, when retrieving the model, post-process it to set the transformer names on the attributes that have the user info.

It’s ugly, but it works, and as a bonus I can assert at runtime the transformers actually **do** exist.

### Concrete Steps

Configure the attributes where you need a transformer like so:
[image: Screenshot of the property attributes]
And then, in code, do this:

```swift
let model = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyModel", withExtension: "momd")!)!
/* Let’s workaround the momc bug where it prints a warning for non-existent transformers but it’s lying. */
let transformerUserInfoKey = "frz-transformer"
for entity in model.entities {
    for property in (entity.properties.compactMap{ $0 as? NSAttributeDescription }) {
        if let transformerName = property.userInfo?[transformerUserInfoKey] as! String? {
            assert(ValueTransformer(forName: .init(transformerName)) != nil)
            property.userInfo?.removeValue(forKey: transformerUserInfoKey)
            property.valueTransformerName = transformerName
        }
    }
}
```

---

Note: I first tried the [MOMC_NO_WARNINGS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/build-settings-reference#Suppress-all-momc-warnings) build setting, but it is apparently not supported anymore.

Comment: That's a good workaround for this bug. It might be better to look up the entity and property directly instead of looping through the model. Then you can be sure that the transformer is set in the correct place instead of knowing that it's in the model somewhere.