# CoreData Transformable compile warning: no NSValueTransformer was found

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, transformable

Following [this Medium article](https://medium.com/better-programming/store-an-array-of-custom-data-types-in-core-data-with-transformable-and-nssecurecoding-631c565589bb) I created the following class:

```
import CoreMotion

public class Attitude : NSObject, NSSecureCoding
{
    public static var supportsSecureCoding = true

    var quaternion: CMQuaternion

    enum Key : String
    {
        case quaternionX
        case quaternionY
        case quaternionZ
        case quaternionW
    }

    public init(quaternion: CMQuaternion)
    {
        self.quaternion = quaternion
    }

    public required init?(coder: NSCoder)
    {
        let x = coder.decodeDouble(forKey: Key.quaternionX.rawValue)
        let y = coder.decodeDouble(forKey: Key.quaternionY.rawValue)
        let z = coder.decodeDouble(forKey: Key.quaternionZ.rawValue)
        let w = coder.decodeDouble(forKey: Key.quaternionW.rawValue)

        quaternion = CMQuaternion(x: x, y: y, z: z, w: w)
    }

    public func encode(with coder: NSCoder)
    {
        coder.encode(quaternion.x, forKey: Key.quaternionX.rawValue)
        coder.encode(quaternion.y, forKey: Key.quaternionY.rawValue)
        coder.encode(quaternion.z, forKey: Key.quaternionZ.rawValue)
        coder.encode(quaternion.w, forKey: Key.quaternionW.rawValue)
    }
}

public class AttitudeTransformer : NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer
{
    public override static var allowedTopLevelClasses: [AnyClass]
    {
        [Attitude.self]
    }

    static func register()
    {
        let className = String(describing: AttitudeTransformer.self)
        let name = NSValueTransformerName(className)
        let transformer = AttitudeTransformer()

        ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(transformer, forName: name)
    }
}
```

I've double checked and set things up correctly on CoreData side it seems:

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Found [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32597065/1971013), but `NSSecureUnarchiveFromDataTransformer` extends the new `ValueTransformer`, so I don't see what I'm missing. Also tried adding `@objc(AttitudeTransformer)`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you register the transformer?

Comment: @loremipsum Yes, I call `register()` just before setting up CoreData stuff. But why would it matter because this is a compile warning?